# How to post data through ajax then use queries

Tags: post, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use swal with ajax to post the active menu item from a dropdown. So when I press a button, the swal function is called and the queries actually work if I specify which record should be deleted, but when I try to use the post var, nothing happens. Resuming, it's a button that deletes the image from database where the id is the active menu item. I have searched a lot on how to use the ajax syntax to post data, but I couldn't make it work, so I went here.

admin.php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="rmv_banner()">Remover</button>
if (isset($_SESSION['taskOption'])) { $_SESSION['taskOption'] = $_POST['taskOption']; }?>
```

The function so far:

```
function rmv_banner(){
swal({
     title: 'Remover este banner ativo?',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Sim, pode remover!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      text: 'Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
      type: 'warning',
      confirmButtonColor: '#F54400',
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'rmv_b.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{},
                success: function(resp)
                      {
                        if(resp) return 'ok',
                          swal(
                            'Banner Removido!',
                            'Este banner foi removido dos ativos com sucesso!',
                            'success'
                          ).then(function() {
                            location.href = 'admin.php';
                          });
                      }
            })
          }
    })
};
```

rmv_b.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('includes/conexao.php');

if (isset($_POST['taskOption'])){
    //Deleta o banner do disco
    $apaga_fisico = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT banner_imagem FROM esc_slider WHERE banner_id = '" . $_POST['taskOption'] . "'"); 
    $fetch_imagem = mysqli_fetch_row($apaga_fisico);
    $caminho_imagem = "images/slider/" . implode($fetch_imagem);
    unlink($caminho_imagem);
    //Deleta o diretório do banner no bando de dados
    $apaga_banco = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM esc_slider WHERE banner_id = '" . $_POST['taskOption'] . "'"); 
    mysqli_query($conexao, $apaga_banco);
    header('location:admin.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Should I put something in "data:{}"?

**UPDATE:**
The if statement in rmv_b.php is not being executed

Comment: _"Should I put somenthing in "data:{}"?"_ - Yes. You should put the data you want to send to the server, or the server will get a post request with no data.

Comment: `{taskOption: 'taskOptionValueHere'}`

Comment: You are also _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. Look into using Prepared Statements instead if inserting user data directly into your database query like that. Right now, anyone can delete _all_ images from your database.

Comment: Just send in a json object. Try: `data: {taskOption: 'what-ever-you-want-to-send'}`. Also, your `header('location: ...')` in your PHP-file won't redirect the client so you can leave that out. If you want to redirect the client after a successful ajax call, it should be in the `success` callback (as you have in your `else`-block).

Comment: the value is writed as $row_banner['banner_id'], I just paste the way it is writed? Not very familiar with ajax syntax

Comment: You also need to return something. You're checking `resp`, but you're not outputting anything in PHP. Output `1` on success and `0` on fail and it should work.

Comment: The data you pass is a json object. It's not specific to Ajax.

Comment: So, i have tried data:{taskOption: taskOption}, but nothing yet

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Isn't the swal message after 'ok' (succes) an output?

Comment: You're not outputting anything in your _PHP_-code. What that ajax function does is making a http request to the PHP file you've defined (`rmv_b.php`) and sends the response from that file to the `success`-callback in the `resp`-variable. If you don't output anything in your PHP-code, then `resp` will be empty and checking an empty variable `if (resp)` will evaluate as false.

Comment: So, without this output, the if statement in rmv_b.php won't be executed?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

As from jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { taskOption: "someOption" }
})
```

You are sending and http post request without parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
function rmv_banner(){
swal({
     title: 'Remover este banner ativo?',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Sim, pode remover!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      text: 'Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
      type: 'warning',
      'taskOption' : taskOption
      confirmButtonColor: '#F54400',
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: ()=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'rmv_b.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{taskOption: taskOption},
                success: function(resp)
                      {
                        if(resp) return 'ok',
                          swal(
                            'Banner Removido!',
                            'Este banner foi removido dos ativos com sucesso!',
                            'success'
                          ).then(function() {
                            location.href = 'admin.php';
                          });
                      }
            })
          }
    })
};
```

Comment: Where does the `taskOption`-variable get defined? Also, when posting an answer, it should include an explanation of what issue you have solved and how.